# How can a change to the male refractory period affect the hierarchial structure of the family?

Tags: society, reproduction

In this world, the cost of reproduction for males is higher due to the refractory period being much longer. After ejaculations occurs, the testes must take time to produce sperm once again. This can take up to several months, during which the male cannot perform or has any interest in sex. Because of this, men cannot "spread their royal oats " as quickly. However, male sperm is much more potent, and is more likely to lead to insemination. This has been present since the early days of humanity.

How could this biological change affect the structure of the nuclear family?

Comment: Does it change the potential fertility of the male?  Is his sperm more "potent" or is the possibility of insemination the same as in our world ?

Comment: Should we assume human female for all other procreation standards?  Also, do you have a hard number of months?

Comment: Can you justify this in an evolutionary manner? Why would males evolve into month-long infertility? With the science-based tag, you will need some sort of justification.

Comment: @kingledion:  This is actually the rule in procreation, not the exception.  In fact, the number of species that are physically capable of having reproductive sex at anytime in the year is quite low (Humans, Bonobos, and Dolphins come to mind).  The Bulk of non-asexual reproduction of life cycles through a mating season.

Comment: @hszmv But, the males can certainly mate more than once in a season. This question isn't about mating seasons, its about one-shot mating, which I don't believe exists in nature (unless you count male spiders that get eaten).

Comment: Does a 30 minute refractory period have any effect on *our* familial hierarchical structure?  I don't think so...

Comment: Are you aware that species subject to estrus period also mate only during the estrus, thus once every few months?

Comment: @L.Dutch and lion prides sure are patriarchal... :)

Comment: @L.Dutch, but that's due to the *females* losing the capacity to become pregnant. Males generally don't bother mating during that time because the females aren't receptive and can't get pregnant anyway, so it's a waste of time. Present a fertile female, and the male is ready to go anytime, anywhere. Consider horses; females have an estrous period, but a stallion that's serving as a stud (as with thoroughbreds) can be mated at any time so long as a fertile female who is in estrous is present.

Comment: opinion-based hold is not justified. Social science are inherently less precise than physics, so it is acceptable to have differing opinions on how things will develop, especially given the fundamental nature of the change that OP proposed.

Comment: @BaldBear, please note that [primarily opinion-based means something different on Worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436/idea-refinement-clarification-and-examples-of-vtc-reasons-for-new-users/6437#6437).

Comment: @BaldBear social sciences are one thing, and they do abide by the scientific method. Extrapolating on a topic with very poor backing is another thing, usually called wishful thinking. That is not a problem here, and the question does not ask for science, it's just that invoking science to justify things here grants you this kind of comment. That said, we say a question is opiniom based when there is no objective way to pick a best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Most animals are like this. There is a mating period (typically in the spring), and then both males and females lose interest in reproduction.

**Edit.** In humans, it will make **marriage much more focused on children**. Men will care a lot less about a "having a soulmate" and "eternal love" once they do not need sex on a regular basis. So expect a lot fewer childless marriages, and more divorces once children have grown up.

It still makes sense to share the burden of operating a modern adult household, but that can be done with roommates, or a "domestic partnerships", which could be between people of same gender, or more than two people.

**Single motherhood will become more common**, b/c there is one less reason for dad to stay, especially if the child is a girl. There are still quite a few men who value raising a child, but there will be a **severe competition** for them among women. And since men have less interest in sex, competition will be over such old-fashioned virtues like skills in childcare and household chores.

if parental support laws survive, some women will take an **alternative path** of using their sexual appeal to get impregnated by a successful male. They will have to: 
 - gamble on who will be earn a lot over the next 20 years, who is "in heat", 
 - use tricks like puncturing a condom, or saving its contents
 - deal with hate from family-oriented women

It will also have major **effect on culture** since so much of it is driven by sexual desires, and you now have eliminated a lot of it. Edit: it is hard to predict cultural change. Much of what men do (sports, general showing off) is about demonstrating their fitness to females. If that motivation is out, there will be more focus on career achievement, and other applications of hunter instincts.

**PS** all of the above assumes your suggested change happens to modern society. If the different **refractory period has been with us since prehistoric times**, society can be completely different. Specifically, we could easily end up with large all-female households, and roaming males making periodic visits. I believe this is how it is with elephants.

Comment: how would it affect culture if much of it is driven by desire.

Comment: @Incognito I don't think that can be answered definitively without looking into the specifics of how that desire is implemented at a biological level. If there is a lot of tension caused by this change, the nature of the tension will matter greatly for looking into how it affects things.  Consider the difference between a dull muscle ache and touching a hot stove.  Both generate tension, but they produce radically different behaviors.

Comment: You make a lot of assertions, but no justifications.

Comment: Estrus isn't the same as what's being proposed. In existing animals, the female loses interest due to ovulation cycles; the male is still plenty capable of sex, but in most species has evolved to not bother trying to have sex until females are in heat because it's a waste of time and energy. You can see this in cattle: there's no need to wait for a specific time to collect sperm from bulls, you just need to stimulate them properly.

Answer (score 1):

In biological terms the male would probably be considered the new 'female', and the female would be considered the new 'male' ([Anisogamy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisogamy)). To come to this conclusion I am using humans as the basis as I think that is what the question is referring to. The OP says males will have a refractory period of several months (availability of sperms is once ever several months). Presumably women will keep the gamete availability period they already have (*once every 28 days, menstrual cycle*). So the availability of the male gamete will become less than that of the female gamete. This will cause a reverse in the direction of the *Anisogamy*.

At least in macro terms. What we could expect then is a reversal of the typical behaviors that are evolved in the male vs female competition to reproduce. Namely who competes for who. These behaviors evolve because they are the most successful strategies for reproducing, and thus are the most favored by evolution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisogamy

> Anisogamy (also called heterogamy) is the form of sexual reproduction
>   that involves the union or fusion of two gametes, which differ in size
>   and/or form. (The related adjectives are anisogamous and
>   anisogamic).[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisogamy) The smaller gamete is considered to be male (sperm
>   cell), whereas the larger gamete is regarded as female (egg cell).
>
> Since females are often the limiting factor in a species reproductive
>   success, males are often expected by the females to search and compete
>   for the female, known as intraspecific competition.[4] This can be
>   seen in organisms such as bean beetles, as the male that searches for
>   females more frequently is often more successful at finding mates and
>   reproducing. In species undergoing this form of selection, a fit male
>   would be one that is fast, has more refined sensory organs, and
>   spatial awareness.[4]

The typical behavior that evolves in this scenario is that the sex with the more plentiful gamete seeks out the one with the scarcer gamete. The sex with the more expensive gamete becomes more careful about how and who they choose to reproduce with, since there is a heavier investment in the exchange working. Really it is economics.

So using Anisogamy, we have a defacto gender reversal (of scarcity, not of who carries the baby, etc).

Other social changes me be difficult to quantify, but this much at least is a certainty; increased competition for males. This may manifest immediately, or after several generations after evolution has had a chance to take hold and makes these behavior innate. But it is pretty much guaranteed.

Comment: As @L.Dutch pointed out, the females of many species only go into estrus a few times per year.  That doesn't make -- for example -- lion prides any less of a patriarchy.

Comment: @ RonJohn, Im not sure how your point contradicts anything I have said? Females are more sought after, even with lions. Male lions fight over which gets to be in charge of the pride and get access to the females. I am pointing out that males will be more valuable in the mating economy since their resource will be less available. In your current example females can reproduce only sometimes  a year and males can reproduce at any time. So exactly in line with what I have said. I don't understand where this patriarchy stuff is coming in? I haven't mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: @ RonJohn, I don't think you understood my answer. I have hopefully made it clearer.

Comment: Almost all (if not actually *all*) animal sexual reproduction systems are anisogamous. The human sexual reproduction system is anisogamous. What has that to do with anything?

Comment: @AlexP is correct.  Lion sperm are tiny relative to the egg, too, yet the lionesses (who's estrus are in sync) only let the lion mate with them a few times per year.

Comment: @AlexP, Anisogamy will be in the opposite direction. Im not sure what is so hard to understand about this.

Comment: @RonJohn, Using your lion example, the simple point is that there will be reproductive role reversal. The question is for humans, so if we translate the time scale into lion's terms. The male lion can mate once every few years, the female can mate once every few months. In this situation, It will be the male dictating when mating occurs, not the female. That is the point. And then all evolutionary pressure that follows from this change is what we will see. That's it. That's my whole point. And this is not an opinion, this is a fact as I understand it.

Comment: I don't see the justification in the analogy of stretching the lion's mating to every few years.  The whole point of me using the lion analogy is that males who don't copulate that often can still form patriarchal hierarchies.

Comment: Let me just get some more sources. What I am trying to communicate is a fact from the field of evolutionary behavior. But I guess no one is familiar with it.

Comment: @RonJohn, Here is the reason for stretching it. In the question we are referring to humans. Human males can attempt to reproduce at any time on any day successfully. Human females can attempt reproduce successfully at most once a month (because one egg per month). So for a human males refactory period to be several months, means that the refactory period is several times longer than the females. If we assume 3 months. That means that males refactory is 3x longer than the females. If we are using lions now, female estrus is once in 4 months, so the equivalent would be males once in 12 months.

Comment: And I think it's an invalid stretch, since **I already accounted for that** by using the lion analogy.

Comment: The recent addition is good, put the part about anisogamy is (still) completely superfluous.

Comment: I am including Anisogamy because it is the explanation for why the competition for males/females reverses. The quote about competing for eggs appears on the same page. I have cleaned up the answer a bit and hopefully it is easier to understand.

Comment: The whole point of this answer is that males are able to reproduce less than females and this fact cant be changed. That is the base assumption.

Comment: *"Human females can attempt reproduce successfully at most once a month (because one egg per month)."* They actually *can* attempt all right, and they actually *do* attempt. In the words of a literary character: *"I like the trying* [to get pregnant], *just don't want it to work."* (Fatima cor Staenbridge, in S. M. Stirling's and David Drake's *Warlord*.)

Comment: You can attempt many times, but you can only attempt and be successful once in a month. Modern males can attempt and be successful many times a month (multiple women/pregnancies). The answer is a reasonable prediction using the information of modern biology. I have made it clearer as requested. I will be making no more edits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the question follows naturally from the condition.

I believe you are assuming the family structure is determined by the male's sexual needs? Things that measurably affect the family structure are the personalities of the members, their beliefs, and the culture in which they grew up / live in.

So my answer is it will not affect the "structure" of the nuclear family, though it would definitely affect the population growth rate. I would imagine sexual relations could be more ceremonial since so much is at stake if reproduction is the goal. Sperm donations would be highly valuable. Surgeries or medications might help males enjoy the sensation more often (since they would undoubtedly have good memories of the experience).

Many facets of the culture would be impacted, but things like polygamy/monogamy are driven by more than sexual desire.